# Can we discourage posting Interactive Ruby Shell dialogues?

Tags: discussion, edits, asking-questions, markdown

People posting Ruby questions often post their code as if it were given in a [Interactive Ruby Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell) (IRB) dialogue, but given the IRB prompt is redundant, annoying, and slows down reading, I think it will be a good idea to discourage people from posting the code like this, and encourage them to post in a static script form, unless giving an interactive dialogue is really necessary. I propose this point to be considered as one criterion for editing as well. Similar things may be said for other languages that have an interactive mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar conflict with scala code. It looks like this:

```
scala> val b = List (4, 11, 17)                    
b: List[Int] = List(4, 11, 17)

scala> val bs = sortSuperSetSum (b)               
bs: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(4, 6, 10, 11, 15, 17, 21)
```

It's

- unfriendly for cut'n' paste
- harder to read
- make horizontal scrolling more likely

but on the other hand it

- produces additional information

  - about types
  - values
- proves executable code

Of course the user can have both, he groups his code, and only shows few interesting, formatted results as comment:

```
val b = List (4, 11, 17)                    
val bs = sortSuperSetSum (b)               
// IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(4, 6, 10, 11, 15, 17, 21)
```

- Is it similar with irb?
- Do you have links?

Comment: Thanks for your opiniton. And thanks to Peter, now my question has a link to wikipedia on irb. You can see its pretty much redundant. In ruby, results are usually shown by `# => ...`.

Answer (score 2):

As a heavy Python user, I find using the shell can be useful sometimes. I agree that the Ruby shell puts too much garbage that distracts from the real code though. My solution is to use the `--simple-prompt` option, which makes it far more readable:

```
$ irb --simple-prompt
>> puts 'hello world'
hello world
=> nil
>>
```

The `=> nil` still gets in the way (is there a way to remove it?), but I think this is at least bareable.

Comment: I didn't know about `--simple-prompt`. Interesting.

Comment: you certainly can avoid the `=>nil`. Try using both of these switches at once: irb --prompt "inf-ruby" --noinspect

Answer (score 1):

IRB's output can be refined to the desired level. Rather discourage its output usage, we can recommend users to try using both of these switches at once:

```
irb --prompt "inf-ruby" --noinspect
```

So the output looks like:

```
C:\Users\ABM>irb --prompt "inf-ruby" --noinspect

irb(main):001:0> puts 'Hello World'

Hello World



irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: That will be better, but if there is no particular need to show the promt in the questions/answers, then it is better to not have it at all.

Comment: I would second your opinion. But this practice is adopted by many bloggers and bash/terminal (*nix/ape) type stakeholders. So its too much to hope that this practice would be avoided at a greater scale in python/ruby and other highly console-dependent languages especially in linux/apple platforms (coz they've a powerful shell base!) WindOS7 & Vista, OTOH, by introducing powershell with .net integration (not very popular thus far), it seems they're also vouching for this custom and yet it's probable that we would see some post with `"This is windOS console".split(" c")` kind of syntax. :)